# Find number of integers such that $n^a =1 \mod p$.

Tags: number-theory

I want to find the number of integers $n$ (modulo a prime $p$) such that $n^a=1 \mod p$. I have a possible method but I know I am doing something wrong.

Suppose the order of $n$ modulo $p$ is $k$. If $k|a$ then $n^a=1 \mod p$. The converse also holds (this can be proven by the euclidean algorithm). Thus we can simply count the number of integers $n$ with order $k$ and sum over all $k|a$. It is well known that the number in question is $\phi(k)$. Summing over all $k|a$ is also a well known sum - its equal to $a$. So my conclusion is that the answer to the problem is $a$.

There is obviously something wrong here as it doesn't hold for small numbers even.

Answer (score 2):

The orders of elements modulo $p$ must be divisors of $p-1$.
So in your sum $$\sum_{d} \phi(d)$$
the only values of $d$ to consider  are divisors of both $a$ and $p-1$, and exactly the divisors of $\gcd(a,p-1)$. And:

$$\sum_{d\mid\gcd(a,p-1)} \phi(d) = \gcd(a,p-1)$$

Comment: Right. But what exactly is the error in my reasoning.

Comment: You assume that every $k\mid a$ is possible for an order modulo $p$. There are $0$ or $\phi(k)$ elements of order $k$, depending on whether $k\mid p-1$ or not. @JoshuaBenabou